# echo a text on form when field is not filled

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I want to print an error message to the screen(on a form) when something is not filled in (in this case it is `name="namePatient"`).

I already made the check but I don't know how to echo a message to the form so users can see it. Should I do this in PHP, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Please show us your codes.

Comment: Use JavaScript for that, Don't have to use PHP for it

Comment: Use jquery validator plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: If you need some basic checking, IMO a plugin is overkill. Just write a few simple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple methods. I suggest you stick to clientside (so not php) because this will be more userfriendly.

The easiest is using the browsers validation, this will trigger on submit of the form:

```
<form><input required title="Please give me a value" /></form>
```

Another method would be a javascript validation (using jQuery to keep demo simple):

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
    var success = true; 
    $(this).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
        if( this.value.length===0){
            success = false; // we've found an error
            $(this).addClass('invalidInput');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('invalidInput'); // don't forget to remove the class if proper value
        }
    });
});
```

---

If you really want PHP:

```
$errors = array();
if( !isset($_POST['example1']) ){ $errors[] = '- Example1 needs to have a value';}
if( !isset($_POST['example2']) ){ $errors[] = '- Example2 needs to have a value';}

if( count($errors) !==0 ){
    echo "The following has gone wrong:<br />\n" . implode("<br />", $errors);
}
```

Comment: The browser will highlight the input, set focus to it and will display a default message, or if specified the title's value. So a message, per request :)